# What is a "wake" in the context of CFD?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-request

I am getting into computational fluid dynamics (CFD). One of my professors mentioned that a **cylindrical wake** would be a good starting point to learn about turbulence modelling when using CFD software. I'm not a native speaker, so I googled

> cylindrical wake CFD

but the results confuse me (also the translations of my dictionary). How is *wake* defined in the context of CFD and what is a good resource to read up on it?

Comment: The wake is just the fluid effects behind the cyclinder.  I don't believe there is a rigorous definition for it.  If you image search for cylinder cfd, you will see plots of several different flow regimes that would hopefully help you get a feel for what he is refering to.

Comment: Thanks, doing this finally lead me to the [Wikipedia entry on wake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake), which even contains something like a definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two comments above are good for the definition of a wake, but in the case of the flow around the cylinder in 2D, the [von Karman vortex street](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_vortex_street) is the canonical problem that your professor was talking about.

Comment: awesome! thank you, that was exactly what he drew on the white board!